# ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor comment breaks jQuery intellisense

Tags: jquery, razor, intellisense

It seems as though there is a bug either in Razor or in MVC.  Given the following code:

```
@* This is necessary to get the jQuery intellisense.  It won't be rendered to the HTML *@
@if (false) { <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script> }

<script>
$().   <- This has intellisense

@* Comment *@
$().   <- This does not have intellisense
</script>
```

As you can see, anything after a Razor comment does not have the jQuery intellisense.  In the errors window in VS2010, I get the message "Javascript Intellisense Message: C:\Src\CSUService\CSUService\Scripts\jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js(68:48) : 'rootjQuery' is undefined"

Does anybody know a way around this?

Comment: Don't use Razor markup in script blocks; it breaks IntelliSense

Comment: This is neither a Razor or MVC issue, it's a visual studio editor issue.  Intelisense is part of the editor window, and it's easily confused.  Call it a bug if you like, but Intelisense is already a highly complex system, and such bugs are going to exist.